# Multiple continuous deployment triggers in VSTS but not in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

We have just recently upgraded from TFS 2015.2.1 to TFS 2017 and were hoping that we get the possibility to have multiple build definitions as a trigger for a release definition. This feature seems to be available for VSTS (according to https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/more-release-definition#continuous-deploymentintegration-and-scheduled-triggers) but is still not available in TFS 2017 (see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/getting-started/release-notes#update-nov16).

Does anyone know why and when this feature will be available in TFS?

Comment: this should be a part of TFS 2017 update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Feature Timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/features-timeline) this feature was released for VSTS on January 5th; `Multiple release triggers with branch and tag filters` and will be released with **TFS 2017 Update 1**; `Release management orchestration improvements – branch conditions, multiple artifact triggers`.

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17687548-add-feature-of-configure-multiple-triggers-for-dif